# Thread 1:signal SIGBART

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode7

I have just started my coding course on Udemy with Xcode. I have got the 7.2 beta I believe. When I was the doing the cat project I encountered this error.

```
//  AppDelegate.swift
//  Cat 2
//
//  Created by Ghiffari on 22/11/2015.
//  Copyright © 2015 Ghifax Games. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
```

The error is at the last line and the error message is "Thread 1:signal SIGBART". Since I have just started I am very confused and i have tried to look at other questions but I do not think there is an answer. This is the coding I have done in my ViewController.swift file

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var catAgeField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet var catAgeResult: UILabel!

@IBAction func catAgeFinder(sender: AnyObject) {

    var catAge=Int(catAgeField.text!)!

    catAge=catAge * 7

    catAgeResult.text="Your cat is \(catAge) in cat years"

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

Also, the three circles to the left of the "@IBAction" is also filled with a greyish dot, if it helps. Please can someone help me. Thank you.

Additional information: the program crashes straight after it is launched, as soon as it is run.

UPDATE: I made a new project and did exactly what I did before and it stopped crashing(However, I had to redo it 4 times). But if anyone is still curious, I am still happy in trying to find out what error I made.

Comment: You're going to need to post the stacktrace.

Comment: what's a stack trace? BTW thank you for the quick reply

Comment: See [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/Instruments_help_articles/ViewingStackTracesRelatedtoYourCode/ViewingStackTracesRelatedtoYourCode.html).

Comment: This code will crash if the text value in the `catAgeField` is not a valid `Int`.  For example `"seven"`, `"7.2"` or even `" 7"` (space `7`).  What are you doing at the time of the crash?

Comment: @trojanfoeI tried doing what it told me to do but it didn't show a stack trace as it ended in less than 10 seconds.

Comment: @vacawama Firstly, thanks for helping but the program crashes straight after I run it, so I don't even have a chance of entering an integer

Answer (score 0):

Signal Sigbart errors can very so i don't know because i don't have the debug log, but usually it can be fixed by going into Main.story board and right clicking on the top left button on the view controller. A drop down thing will come down and if there are any yellow error icons simply click the x next to them. These are empty connections that cause an error because there is nothing attached. This is usually the result of connecting an IBOutlet or IBAction but then deleting it or undoing the connection, without the connection being fully terminated.